# In Pet Sematary, why did Jud show Louis that the dead could be brought back?

Tags: pet-sematary

Why did he do that if he knew the devastating consequences it would cause?

Comment: Is Jud in any other King works? Any clues to any greater agenda he may have had? I agree that it was a bit weird to share this information with him, but necessary for the plot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The corruption in pets seems minor. The animal comes back a bit meaner, but not evil. Therefore, the minor personality change likely seemed reasonable compared to the family's grief over a lost pet. It's burying humans there that seems to attract the truly evil spirits.

> Jud smiled—or at least his lips slanted. “I think it’s a dangerous place,” he said softly, “but not for cats or dogs or pet hamsters. Go on and bury your animal, Louis.”

Answer (score 1):

Jud admits later to Louis that he did it for selfish/invented reasons: he had a secret and he wanted badly to share it.

> “Lester did it and Stanny did it for the same reason I did it. You do it because it gets hold of you. You do it because that burial place is a secret place, and you want to share the secret, and when you find a reason that seems good enough, why..,” Jud took his hands away from his face and looked at Louis with eyes that seemed incredibly ancient, incredibly haggard. ”Why then you just go ahead and do it. You make up reasons they seem like good reasons.. but mostly you do it because you want to. Or because you have to.”

That last part is also suggestive: several times the book suggests the entity in the woods has some sort of hypnotic power, forcing Jud to sleep and the truck driver to needlessly speed. Jud later tells Louis he was manipulated by that power.

> “Its an evil, curdled place, and I had no business taking you up there to bury that cat. I know that now. It has a power youll beware of if you know whats good for your family and whats good for you. I wasnt strong enough to fight it. You saved Normas life, and I wanted to do something for you, and that place turned my good wish to its own evil purpose. It has a power and I think that power goes through phases, same as the moon. Its been full of power before, and Im ascared its coming around to full again. Im ascared it used me to get at you through your son.”

Comment: I’m on my mobile right now, so I’d appreciate if someone could format this a bit better.